# Does asp.net webform encrypt data for a simple form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, webforms, web-testing

I have a simple asp.net web-form which also has login section. When login form is submitted does asp.net web-form encrypt data before sending it over HTTP.

I have this doubt due to netspark website scan.

I have same application in MVC and as well as asp.net web form also.

When i run `netspark community edition` on both application with similar login form then i only get Vulnerability warning as  `Password Transmitted over HTTP` only for MVC based application but not asp.net webform based application.

Answer (score 3):

No, HTTP does not encrypt form data. ASP.NET just uses the HTTP protocol, and is no better than that.

What you should use is HTTP**S**, the secure variant of the HTTP protocol, which relies on certificates in order to encrypt the data between server and client so it is less likely you become victim of a man-in-the-middle attack.

I guess there is a different configuration (HTTP vs. HTTPS) on both applications, which may explain the issue.